# My php document doesn't redirect to my link after uploading the website and database to the server

Tags: php, html, web-hosting

I finished my website and decided to upload it to the hosting server and make it public. After loading the website to the hosting server my php documents are sending data to the database fine, but it doesn't redirect to the link that I redirected it, and it stays in the php document. I don't know why is this happening. Before uploading the website to the hosting server, in the local server it was redirecting to the link.

Here I attach my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "servername";
$username = "name";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";

//Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die ("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql ="INSERT INTO clientesdudas (user_id, nombreapellido, email, mensaje)
VALUES (NULL, '$_POST[nombre]', '$_POST[correoElectronico]', '$_POST[mensaje]')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  header("Location: http://www.website.com/");
  //echo "Tu mensaje se ha mandado correctamente, nos pondremos en contacto contigo lo más temprano posible. Gracias! <br> <a href='http://www.example.com/'><i class='fas fa-home'></i>Volver a Inicio</a>";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure its working fine? As far as I know you have to escape $_POST variables like `$_POST['nombre']` . Also not sure if you can use $_POST in your statement, maybe predeclare it like `$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];` and use $nombre in your statement. You should also never access POST variables directly and rather use a [filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php). Tell me if it works and I will add it as an answer.

Comment: $_POST [nombre] is syntactically wrong. I dont think query is executing or inserting values correctly.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. Yes, it works fine in my localhost, but when I upload the website to hosting server, the data is inserted to the database, but the page does not reload to the established link it stays in the page where the php document it is in the project.

Comment: @CoderSam — No, it isn't. Implicit constants are a terrible idea, but the synax is allowed.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: header redirection fails when  many output is send before redirection. I suggest you to use ob_start() function at start of the page.